# Query INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Tengo este query:

```
select T1.Item_No,
       T1.Description,
       T1.Min_Quantity,T1.Max_Quantity,sum(T3.Quantity) AS RECIBIDA, 
       SUM(T4.Quantity) AS USADO 
from Purchasing_v_Item T1
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Line_Item T2 ON T1.Item_Key = T2.Item_Key
RIGHT JOIN Purchasing_v_Receipt_e T3 ON T2.Line_Item_Key = T3.Line_Item_Key
RIGHT JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Usage_e T4 ON T2.Item_Key = T4.Item_Key
where T1.Item_Key = 378587 
      AND T3.Receive_Date BETWEEN '9/01/2019' AND '9/23/2019' 
      and T3.Supplier_No = 191411 
      AND T4.Transaction_Type_Key = 3 
      AND T4.Usage_Date BETWEEN '9/01/2019' AND '9/23/2019'
GROUP BY T1.Item_No,T1.Description,T1.Min_Quantity,T1.Max_Quantity
```

Que me trae un saldo de mi inventario usado y comprado, pero no se por que razón me lo multiplica la cantidad de usado y comprado.

Comment: Posiblemente es por que tu consulta con los inner te da como resultado múltiples registros repetidos y la operación Sum le aplica a todo el resultado

Comment: DE HECHO YA LO REVISE ES POR QUE TOMA EL RANGO DE FECHAS Y DONDE TIENE DATOS EN UNA COLUMNA Y LA OTRA NO SE RELLENA EN CON LA INFORMACION Y SE COMIENZA A REPETIR YA AGREGER SUM(ISNULL(T2.Quantity,0)),SUM(ISNULL(T3.Quantity,0))  PERO ME SIGUE REPITIENDO

Comment: ES UN poco complicado ayudar ya que no podemos hacer las pruebas necesarias puesto que no tenemos las tablas  con alguna información para testear.